# django template extends does not work

Tags: django

I don't know what I got wrong, but I cannot get template extension working.

What I want to do:

Say, the page will look like [this (click me to see the screenshot)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ep95Rfkjn0Y1lmcXFzSWdqTFU/edit?usp=sharing). The yellow area is where is customisable.

I created 2 .html pages. 1 is the base (accountbase.html), 1 is the extended (accountregister.html).

[accountbase.html (right click open to see screenshot)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ep95Rfkjn0UTlMdnA1X2ZGLVU/edit?usp=sharing) Remember to click on 100%.

.

.
The yellow area in the base html (id="custom_content")  is what to be extended (replaced).

My accountregister.html page is like this:

```
{%extends "accountbase.html" %}

{% block custom_content %}


<h2>account register page.</h2>


{% endblock %}
```

And I have checked that my view is wired to the correct html page:

```
def register(request):
    return render_to_response('accountregister.html')
```

.
But http:// 1 2 7.0.0.1:8000/account/register/ only displays the base template. What could be wrong????

Many thanks for any suggestion.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a `{% block custom_content %}` in `accountbase.html`? Otherwise it won't work.

So the base template should have:

`{% block custom_content %}{% endblock %}`

and `accountregister.html` should have your content:

```
{% block custom_content %}

<h2>account register page.</h2>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! you are right. I did not get the base template right.. Thank u so so so so much! You are a Saint!